# What can cause "Invalid command '%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}'"

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

While browsing my site, not even making any modifications to it, the whole thing suddenly 500's on me. Error log is full of this:

```
Invalid command '%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Google finds 0 results for this. What could possibly cause this? I am using the Wordfence plugin for WordPress, which occasionally modifies `.htaccess`, but it hasn't ever done this before, and looking through the file I don't see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Discovered this line:

```
%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [NC,OR]
```

which obviously should have been:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [NC,OR]
```

I will have to look into how WordFence works exactly--not sure why it would suddenly introduce syntax errors...